# How to create a date difference value based on conditional logic in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a numeric field in a dataframe based on boolean logic. How do I check and format the values of date columns to result in a numeric value?

There is a sold date and a cancel date, both loaded as string/objects. There is also a "Churn" column that has a 1 if the user has canceled, 0 if they have not.

'fd' = frozen date, to be perceived as "today's date'

CustomerLife Field = If Churn == 0, perform 'fd'-'date sold', else perform 'cancel date'-'date sold'.

Sample of df dates:
Date Sold: 1/1/2017
Date of Cancellation: 3/5/2018

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)

fd = date(2019, 6, 20) #frozen date

df['CL'] = [days_between(fd,df['Date Sold']) 
            if x==0 
            else days_between(df['Date of Cancellation'],df['Date Sold']) 
            for x in df['Churn']]
```

```py
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the inbulit `to_datetime` function from pandas. It will directly parse a Pandas Series object to datetime, you don't really need your `days_between` function, you can just `df.loc` to get the rows and simply subtract.